# Split 1D Binary Array into 2D Array of Consecutive Ones Only

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, array-splice

Imagining I want to split a binary ID array arr into 2D array newArr of consecutive ones interspersed between zeros. Furthermore I want to collect the corresponding indices of the selected ones in a 2D array named Index.

> arr = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1];

Expected results:

> newArr = [[1, 1, 1] , [1, 1],[1, 1]];
>
> Index = [[3,4,5], [7,8],[10,11]];

My attempt of this problem is attached, but is no good.

```js
var arr = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1];

var newArr = [];
let i = arr.length
while(i--){
  if ((arr[i]===1) && (arr[i+1]===1)){
   newArr.push(arr.splice(0,3));
  }
}

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array and collect the items which have a predecessor or a successor.

```js
const
    getConnectedParts = array => array.reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
        if (!v || !a[i - 1] && !a[i + 1]) return r;
        if (!a[i - 1]) {
            r.values.push([]);
            r.indices.push([]);
        }
        r.values[r.values.length - 1].push(v);
        r.indices[r.indices.length - 1].push(i);
        return r;
    }, { values:[], indices: [] });

var array = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    { values, indices } = getConnectedParts(array);

values.map(a => console.log(...a));
indices.map(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If I want to extend the problem to multidimensional input array, how do I tweak the code. Say I have array = [  [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],[1, 0, 1, 1, 0],[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1] ], and I want to perform the same operation on each inner array. I have tried to tweak your code to solve the problem, but I've not been successful. Please, kindly assist.

Comment: you could move the conversion into a function and map the result of the function. mabe you need to change the structure of the result objects.